# C# Ninject ActionFilters not being bound to controller

Tags: c#, ninject

I am trying to use Ninject to bind an `ActionFilter` to a controller where the controller has a `FilterAttribute`, but cannot get the ActionFilters to fire.

My filters and attributes are defined as:

```
public class AuthorisationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter {...}

public class AuthoriseAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {...}
```

I then have a controller with the `Authorise` attribute declared:

```
[Authorise]
public class HomeController : Controller {...}
```

No matter how I try to use a Ninject module to bind the filter to the controller...:

```
Kernel
  .BindFilter<AuthorisationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
  .WhenControllerHas<AuthoriseAttribute>();

Kernel
  .BindFilter<AuthorisationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
  .WhenControllerType<HomeController>();

Kernel
  .BindFilter<AuthorisationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0);
```

... the filters just don't fire.

Registering the filters in the GlobalFilterCollection doesn't help. Is there some other place the filters are supposed to be registered?

Thanks

Comment: IS this MVC or WebAPI project?

Comment: @cvbarros This is an MVC project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I'm not using the `NinjectHttpApplication` to extend my `HttpApplication` class, and so the `DependencyResolver` was not being set (I'm presuming this is set by Ninject if you do use their implementation).

So a simple instruction to set the DependecyResolver results in the custom ActionFilters being instantiated and fired:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

Thanks